# Customizing factor in aggregate tool in ArcMap

Tags: raster, arcmap, resolution, resampling, aggregation

I have a raster of 30m cell size, with either value 0 or 1.
I try to aggregate this into a 1000m cell size. I can then see the proportion of '1's, in a 1000m cell size raster.

But the Aggregate tool only lets me use a round number as a factor, so the closest I get is with factor 33x (to cell size 990m).

I would then need to resample 990m to 1000m this introduces error, so just resampling won't work

FOR ILLUSTRATION:

Here's an example of one aggregated cell sourced from 30x30m cells with 0/1 values, now in an aggregate raster at 990x990m cell size:

[image]

The two original cells are correctly aggregated into a 990x990m cell, and the sum of all values that were of interest (value '1') is 2. You can see these same two cells in the resampled cell on the right, in the top of the cell.

But due to the resampling, the raster has shifted and includes more of the 30x30m cells. Yet, the cell value for the now resampled aggregate raster is still 2, while this is an incorrect value and should be 5.

Comment: Resample to lowest common denominator (10m), then aggregate to 1000m.

Comment: No that won't work, I'm adding more details above